# What does the word "however" mean in the sentence below?

Tags: vocabulary

What does the word "however" mean in the sentence below?

> A nonlinear system's state, however, can go to infinity in finite
> time.

Comment: Have you looked up "however" in a dictionary?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, but I think that's not required to be there! Does the meaning change if we ignore that?

Comment: Yes, its omission would change the meaning. In your example, "however" is a connective adverb/adjunct linking the clause with some preceding text. It expresses contrast or an adversative meaning. That meaning would be lost if you dropped it, leaving simply the modal meaning of possibility or ability..

Comment: Incidentally, "however" could be replaced with "by contrast".

Comment: It is in contrast to the previous sentence: *The state of an unstable linear system can go to infinity as time approaches infinity.* That defines a **linear** system, and the next sentence (quoted) defines a **nonlinear** system.

Comment: @WeatherVane Wow how do u find the original text??!!

Comment: I searched for your exact quote, and it turned up a lot of very similar teaching material.  I just picked one because everybody copies everybody else's material.